# Combining css, html, and js in templates/ folder

Tags: javascript, python, django

I usually see variations on this project structure in django, where the static files are managed by apache or nginx:

```
app/
  - views.py
static/
    js/
      - base.js
    img/
    css/
      - base.css
templates/
  - home.html
manage.py
urls.py
settings.py
```

However, for a tiny app, is the following an acceptable approach?

```
app/
  - views.py
templates/
  - base.js
  - base.css
  - home.html
manage.py
urls.py
settings.py
```

If it's a terrible approach, could someone please explain why? For me, it seems like often a template html file contains inline css or javascript for a particular override or convenience, so the above approach doesn't seem that much different for a small application.

Comment: Assuming you want an approach that would actually work, this is a terrible one because it wouldn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in home.html could I not include the first line to be `{% include "base.js" %} {% include "base.css" %}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static/` directory should only be used for static content, aka `.js`, `.css`, and image files.

The `template/` directory should only be used by `.html` files because they are loaded from django views. Separating your `.html` files can also be useful for security reasons (all static directory is public, so you don't have to apply any sub-directories access rules).

You don't really have to necessary separate your static files in subdirectories if you only have 2 or 3 files, but I whould suggest you to do so. When your project will be a bit bigger, the structure will be ok, no additional refactor work to do...

Answer (score 0):

Every app you create should be provided it's own `static`,`templates`,`media`,`urls` directory.For example in `templates` django advices you to create a subfolder and name it what you have named your app..If you don't do this and choose to do it other way , it will still work but this way is more pythonic and django insists you to be pythonic .. Yo can refer to this link for [Django Docs | Design Principles.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/misc/design-philosophies/)